# How return data from collection in arangodb udf

Tags: arangodb

I want to return some document from my collection in user defined function.

```
/* path/to/file.js */
'use strict';


function dimcity(number)
{   
return {FOR d IN Dim_City 
FILTER d.id >= number 
RETURN d};

}

module.exports = dimcity;
```

but it give a error, so how i can return a documents from collection in user defined function.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that! The docuentation states:

> Modification of global variables is unsupported, as is reading or changing the data of any collection from inside an AQL user function.

See https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/extending-conventions.html#variables-and-side-effects

Comment: Could you please add what they should do instead of using user defined functions?